# React native Web browser error. Always showing object Object in browser

Tags: reactjs, react-native

on my react native iOS render my input changes when I type text but in the browser, it automatically returns `object Object`.
[image: objcet Object image]

Comment: can you show us some of your code so that we can help you?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.